# CSS selector cascading/specificity not working as expected

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

### Details

I'm working in FirefoxDeveloperEdition and experiencing unexpected selector prioritization. I've read through the [*Smashing Magazine* article "CSS Specificity: Things You Should Know"](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and, insofar as I can tell, have constructed the CSS selectors as they ought be in order to achieve the intended level of specificity for each. However, the wrong declaration is being cancelled out.

What's the issue, here? Have I not quite wrapped by head around the workings of selector specificity? Is this a bug? Or, something else?

### Project Code (simplified)

**/index.html**

```
<head>
  <link href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="hud">
    <section class="main float-l">
      <a href="#0" class="button">
        <div class="outer container">
          <div class="inner container">
            <p class="show"> <!-- This text is meant to be white by the style declared at line 159. But, it's grey by line 61. -->
              View Details
            </p>
            <div class="arrow"></div>
            <p class="hide"> <!-- This text is meant to be white by the style declared at line 159. But, it's grey by line 61. -->
              Hide Details
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </section>
  </section>
</body>
```

**/css/style.css**

```
58  .hud > .main p /* I also tried `.hud > .main p:not(.button)` */
59    {
60      vertical-align:   middle;
61      color:            #7C7C7C; /* This grey is applied of the white of line 159. */
62    {
```

...

```
155 .hud > .main > .button
156   {
157     display:          block;
158     background-color: #986B99;
159     color:            #FFFFFF; /* This white should be applied, but is overridden by the grey of line 61. */
160     height:           36px;
161     margin:           20px 10px 10px;
162     padding:          8px 20px;
163     font-weight:      400;
164     text-decoration:  none;
165     text-transform:   uppercase;
166     border-radius:    2px;
167   }
```

### Inspector

Tried `.hud > .main > .button` vs `.hud > .main p`
[image: Firefox dev tools inspector showing overridden CSS]

Also tried `.hud > .main > .button` vs `.hud > .main p:not(.botton)`
[image: Firefox dev tools inspector showing overridden CSS]

Comment: What is your expected outcome, and what is your actual outcome? You haven't told us that crucial part yet. Also, a JSFiddle example would be very helpful.

Comment: Well for one, button is an `a`, not a `p`.

Comment: @TylerH As mentioned in the comments of the CSS code blocks, I'm expecting the `p` elements inside the `.button` to have white text.

Comment: In the future, you should put your expected outcomes in plain text, not leave them buried in code comments. I want to know what I'm looking for *before* I look at the code.

Comment: @Chad what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: @TJWalker He's targeting `p:not(.button)` and expecting that to change the color of his button?

Comment: @TylerH "buried"? It's about the same it'd be with out the code block except it has a grey background lol! Oh, and it's in context.

Comment: @Chad I think I see what you're saying. But, the `p` is a descendant, not child, of `.button` so why would it matter that the `p`s have and `a` between them and `.main` in `.hud > .main p:not(.button)`?

Comment: Buried because you spend several sentences at the top of the post describing what I expect to be the "details" of the problem but are in fact just details of how specificity is supposed to work. And then you don't have any more prose at all for the rest of the post. My point stands; we need to know what your expected outcome is *before* looking at your code.

Comment: @TylerH Whatever you say, man. Feel free to edit the post and show me how it ought to be. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Chad are you saying it ought to be `.hud > .main p:not(.button p)`?

Comment: @TJWalker from what I understand he's saying that the `.hud > .main  p:not(.button)` should not be overwriting `.hud > .main > .button`, but when button is an anchor, the `.hud > .main p:not(.button)` won't affect it. For it to matter, it should be `.hud > .main a:not(.button)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because first style matches the element and the second one is inherited from it's parent.

Specificity only plays its role when two selectors matches the same element. Not when it comes to style inheritance from parent elements.

You can see that on really simple example:

```css
#myID {
  color: red;
}

p {
  color: green;  
}
```

```html
<div id="myId">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Even though `#myId` is more specific text is green because `p` selector matches that element directly and therefor is more important than `color` inherited from `div`.

To make `p` elements inside `.button` white you need:

```
.hud > .main > .button p {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Specificity does not work through inheritance. Ahhh, okay! Great, thanks.